# Wait For Asynchronous Operation To Complete in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

I am not sure how to handle this situation as I am very new to iOS development and Swift. I am performing data fetching like so:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)!)
{
    loadShows()
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
    println("Background Fetch Complete")
}
```

My loadShows() function parses a bunch of data it gets from a website loaded into a UIWebView. The problem is that I have a timer that waits for 10 seconds or so in the loadShows function. This allows for the javascript in the page to fully load before I start parsing the data. My problem is that the completion handler completes before my loadShows() does.

What I would like to do is add a bool for "isCompletedParsingShows" and make the completionHandler line wait to complete until that bool is true. What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you have to pass your async function the handler to call later on:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)!) {
    loadShows(completionHandler)
}

func loadShows(completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)!) {
    //....
    //DO IT
    //....

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
    println("Background Fetch Complete")
}
```

## OR (cleaner way IMHO)

add an intermediate completionHandler

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: ((UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)!) {
    loadShows() {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)
        println("Background Fetch Complete")
    }
}

func loadShows(completionHandler: (() -> Void)!) {
    //....
    //DO IT
    //....
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: mind this is a MINIMAL and concrete example but the approach is basically the same everywhere..... you pass the handler on OR you create a new closure that acts as an intermediate (often cleaner IMO)

Comment: How is this function used? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

two ways to solve this, both use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html) (which is similar in Swift and Objective C):

1. change *loadShows* method to make it synchronous and use the same dispatch queue as *completionHandler*, then wrap the entire body of the method in a *dispatch_async*  ; this way the method call ends right away, but the completionHandler will be called after loadShows if finished, just like in a synchronous program
2. use a GCD semaphore - just like the BOOL you mention, but created with *dispatch_semaphore_create* ; you call *dispatch_semaphore_wait* before *completionHandler* to make it wait for the semaphore to be unlocked (unlock it with *dispatch_semaphore_signal* ) ; remember to place your method body inside a *dispatch_async* call in order not to have it block the rest of the app while waiting for loadShows to complete.

Comment: Can you provide an example of #2? I can't seem to find any using swift and this is good information to understand.

Comment: not everybody can call the continue code inside a completion closure, the GCD solution is the best in my opinion, very similar to other synchronous solutions in other languages, use RoNIT link to an example, its easy to understand

Answer (score 2):

### Details

xCode 9.2, Swift 4

### Solution

```
class AsyncOperation {

    private let semaphore: DispatchSemaphore
    private let dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue
    typealias CompleteClosure = ()->()

    init(numberOfSimultaneousActions: Int, dispatchQueueLabel: String) {
        semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: numberOfSimultaneousActions)
        dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: dispatchQueueLabel)
    }

    func run(closure: @escaping (@escaping CompleteClosure)->()) {
        dispatchQueue.async {
            self.semaphore.wait()
            closure {
                self.semaphore.signal()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let asyncOperation = AsyncOperation(numberOfSimultaneousActions: 1, dispatchQueueLabel: "AnyString")
asyncOperation.run { completeClosure in
    // sync/async action
    // ...


    // action complete        
    completeClosure()
}
```

### Full sample

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let asyncOperation = AsyncOperation(numberOfSimultaneousActions: 1, dispatchQueueLabel: "AnyString")
    var counter = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 40))
        button.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

    }

    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        print("Button tapped at: \(Date())")
        asyncOperation.run { completeClosure in
            let counter = self.counter
            print("     - Action \(counter) strat at \(Date())")
            self.counter += 1

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                sleep(1)
                print("     - Action \(counter) end at \(Date())")
                completeClosure()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

### Results

[image]